# How to use "this" keyword inside jquery delegate function?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show a hidden character on mouseover using delegate.

This is the example code.
The alert is working fine. But the hidden a is not getting displayed.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

     <script type='text/javascript'>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a.del").hide();
        this.showHidden = function(event){
        if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
            alert("X");
        $(this).closest(".del").show();
        }
        };
        $("#holder").delegate("div.inner", "hover", this.showHidden);
     });
    </script>
    <div id='holder'>
        <div class='inner' style="background-color:red">a
            <a class='del'>X</a></div>
        <div class='inner' style="background-color:red">a
            <a class='del'>X</a></div>
        <div class='inner' style="background-color:red">a
            <a class='del'>X</a></div>
        <div class='inner' style="background-color:red">a
            <a class='del'>X</a></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are defining a function, you don't need to add this before it like you are doing in `this.showHidden = function(event){`. In your code, you can directly add the function to the delegate as an anonymous function or define it outside with out a this and refer it. The `$(this)` inside the function refers to object on which delegate is triggered, in this case `div.inner` on which mouse the `hovered`. Then we are trying to `find` all the elements inside the div with class `.del` and showing them. you can use other functions like `children` too.

Here is the working code in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/otiko4/5)

```
$("a.del").hide();
        $("#holder").delegate("div.inner", "hover", function(event){
          if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
            alert("X");
            $(this).find(".del").show();
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `.closest()`. That goes up the tree to find a match. You should either be using `$('.del',this)` or `$(this).children('.del')` to find the anchor within the div.

- [.children() Help](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Comment: Actually it's down the tree, if you use that analogy. Trees doesn't have their root at the top. A tree is not a very good analogy for a hierarchy.

Comment: CoSc tree data structures are always shown with the root at the top… http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)

Answer (score 0):

i think instead of using closest, you can just narrow it down and use children as like below.

http://jsfiddle.net/47Vjy/

but i'm not quite sure why are u trying to use delegate though?
from my understanding it's use when you have ajax codes overwriting your html and you need the javascript events to be refreshed too?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The li will gets updated dynamically. But i thought after taking the mouse out, the X will hide. But it seems like its not hiding again.

Answer (score 0):

The bit where you define showHidden as a function is creating a global which is probably not what you want. The reason for this is that the callback is called using the [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) function with `this` set to the document. I think what you want is a local `var showHidden`. Then, this is available because of the closure created when you set up your delegate method. The `$(this)` inside `showHidden`'s body will be correctly set to the element that's being matched because delegate uses the `apply` function and sets `this` as well. All that being said, your callback is so short, I would just inline it in the call to delegate as an anonymous function.

Plus, this is all moot because you can do what you want to do [with CSS!](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes)

```
div#holder a.del { 
    display:none; 
}
div#holder:hover a.del {
    display:inline;
}
```

Some older browsers don't support this, but this is the ideal way to go so you don't even have to use JS at all.